# REGEX filtering on time

Tags: regex, validation

Looking to use Regex to filter time information. My idea is as follows:

Sample Inputs:

```
..."sunday\":[[\"1...
..."sunday\":[[\"2...
..."sunday\":[[\"3...
...
..."sunday\":[[\"9:59...
```

Essentially, I am looking to filter times that come before 10:00 on Sunday. My data comes in the following format, with the preceding and latter part of the string denoted by "..." as text representing other days of the week. I am looking to create a regex that is able to accomplish this. All of the sample input should pass. Example of input that would fail:

```
..."sunday\":[[\"11:00...
..."sunday\":[[\"10:01...
..."sunday\":[[\"12:01...
```

THank you!

Comment: What have you try to achieve your need ?

Comment: Where are you using this? Is is the text inside a file or is it some variable dump in the console/string literal? What is the rule to match a string: when it contains `sunday":[["<00:00-10:59>`?

Comment: trying to use in a JQ script in a test() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.+?sunday.+?"[0-9]:\d+.+`

It checks for anything + sunday + anything + an hour format that suits your < 10:00 requirement.

Test it here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CSbBdX/2/)

Comment: Doesn't match `sunday, "9:00"`.

Comment: Yeah, coz in his example something comes before sunday. If you want that to match just substitute the + for *

Comment: Why put `.+?` in your regex at all?

Comment: @melpomene Because: ..." implies something has to come before sunday, but it doesn't matter what it is.